# Using Angular timer in ionic3

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

I am using angular timer(i.e. http://siddii.github.io/angular-timer/index.html#/markup5 ) in ionic3, but when i put the timer tag in html page, then have error. Don’t know what need to do.

```
<timer end-time="{{timelimit.timeLimitDate}}">{{days}} days, {{hours}} hours, {{minutes}} minutes, {{seconds}} seconds.</timer>
```

the error:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
'timer' is not a known element:
1. If 'timer' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of 
this module.
2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("ate}}">{{days}} days, {{hours}} hours, {{minutes}} minutes, {{seconds}} seconds.</timer>-->
```

Did anyone know what need to do, thanks a lot~

Comment: This is a common error when you don´t declare or import component/module in your App module. Before using it you should import it, but looking at the library I think it isn´t ready to use with new versions of Angular...

Answer (score 0):

You **can not** use above timer with `Ionic 3`.Because it uses `AngularJS`.You need to find an Angular module for that.

I think you can use this [**ng2-simple-timer**](https://github.com/J-Siu/ng2-simple-timer-example) module on your Ionic app.

*Add `SimpleTimer` into module providers (eg. `app.module.ts`).*

```
import { SimpleTimer } from 'ng2-simple-timer';

@NgModule({
    providers: [SimpleTimer]
})
```

More [**info is here**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-simple-timer).